# Interrupt signal names don't work over ssh: bad trap

Tags: bash, ssh, trap, interrupt

If run over `ssh`, a script with a trap statement with interrupt signal names (`SIGINT`, etc) gives an error and the trap does not work when an interrupt (eg. Ctrl+C) is sent. Eg:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'echo "Exit signal detected..."' SIGINT

# display something
echo "This is a test"

sleep 100000
```

When this is run *over `ssh`*, it prints an error

> trap: SIGINT: bad trap

and `trap`'s command is never executed.

The problem is over `ssh` only; if run locally it works.

However, if the interrupt signal number (`2`) is used instead the name (`SIGINT`), it works including over `ssh`.

I thought it's preferable to use signal names and not signal numbers.

EDIT: Local system is running Fedora 28, and remote system is on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Is the system you're SSHing to a different operating system to what you use local? This might explain the different behaviours.

Comment: @mhutter They are different: local = Fedora 28, remote = Ubuntu 18.04. Is ssh not standard?

Comment: @Goro Do you mean `trap '' SIGINT; ssh [remote IP]` ? I tried this and the behavior was the same.

Comment: @JosephSible Just using `INT` without the `SIG` part works! Still confused about the cause, since the solution you linked to mentions different shells might behave differently, but in this case both local and remote use bash.

Comment: @adatum are you positive that your remote shell is bash? Or is it “/bin/sh”, which invokes posix mode....

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode

Comment: @JeffSchaller The remote is Ubuntu 18.04 and `echo $SHELL` gives `/bin/bash`. Is there something else I can check?